# creating a ConcurrentBag using a template

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

The below code has been written to create a pool of arrays made of lists. I want to use it later in parallel foreach. To create the pool I want to copy over a pre-populated template.

```
List<candle>[] sourceCandleList = new List<candle>[3];
// populate sourceCandleList here with data
ConcurrentBag<List<candle>[]> poolList = new ConcurrentBag<List<candle>[]>();
int maxThreads = 64;
for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
{
    poolList.Add(sourceCandleList);
}
```

Does this create 64 deep copies of sourceCandleList? If not, is the ConcurrentBag still thread-safe?
The reason why I'm not sure is because all the lists in the ConcurrentBag seem to go empty if I clear `sourceCandleList` like `sourceCandleList.Clear()`.

Comment: Instances of a concurrentbag are thread-safe. Nothing changes to the thread safety of the object instances you store. And no, there is no magic in the add method, no deep-copy or shallow-copy operation is executed.

Comment: Are different threads going to use the same instance of `List<candle>[]`, `List<candle>` or `candle`?

Comment: @rene But I add the same object 64 times.

Comment: @Yacoub Massad No, each of the 64 added instances of sourceCandleList would be used by only one thread. So no thread should access the same List<candle>[] or any of it's components in the same time. I use `while (!poolList.TryTake(out CandleList))` in the beginning of each thread.

Comment: But there are not 64 instances. They is a single instance that is added 64 times to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ConcurrentBag itself is still thread-safe, but this code is ultimately just adding 64 pointers to the bag that all reference the same array of List objects. It's the same array added 64 times, so any change made to one array will happen to all of them.

You'd need to manually make a deep copy of each array, each list within each array, and potentially each candle (if that's a class and not an immutable struct). It'd end up looking something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
{
    List<candle>[] candleList = new List<candle>[3];
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        candleList[j] = new List<candle();
        foreach (candle c in sourceCandleList[j])
            candleList[j].Add(new candle(c.field1,c.field2)); // If it's an immutable struct, you should be able to just .Add(c)
    }
    poolList.Add(candleList);
}
```

You could probably do it jiggier with LINQ, but I'm not sure which version of .NET you're running.

Comment: @Manngo lol I can't respond to your comment either, but no, ConvertAll will make a new List, but the items will be the same (assuming candle is an object). Your safest bet is to just instantiate a new a new candle.

Comment: Just for fun, a follow up: I'm sure this solution is absolutely correct since after implementing it I ran out of memory :-). But this is a whole new story... I simply changed to x64, now testing. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

@zfrank
Sorry, I could not post this as a comment.
Would the below also do the trick of creating a deep copy? In my understanding ConvertAll creates a deep copy.

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
     {
      List < candle >[] CandleList = new List<candle>[sourceCount];
      for (int w = 0; w <= sourceCount - 1; w++)
           {
                CandleList[w] = sourceCandleList[w].ConvertAll(c => c);
           }
           poolList.Add(CandleList);
      }
```

Comment: No, `.ConvertAll(c => c)` would create a shallow copy of the list. However, it won't matter because every list is empty so it does not matter if the list is a shallow or deep copy.